# Why is my FloatingActionButton missing in my display?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

The fragment and code should show the list `(android:id="@+id/rv_groups")`, if any groups are existing in the list, otherwise it should show the text `("android:id=@+id/tv_noGroups")`.

The `FloatingActionButton` should be displayed for both cases, however it only shows when the list is displayed. It does not appear when it is showing the `@+id/tv_noGroups` display. How is that fixed?

Here is fragment layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_groups"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/padd_5"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_noGroups"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padd_5">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is code handling the fragment:

```
public class GroupsFragment extends Fragment
{
    private Context m_context = null;
    private RecyclerView rv_groups;
    private GroupListAdapter adapter = null;
    private TextView tv_noGroups;
    private GroupListViewModel m_groupViewModel;

    public GroupsFragment ()
    {} // Required empty public constructor

    @Override
    public void onAttach (Context context)
    {
        super.onAttach(context);
        m_context = context;
        adapter = new GroupListAdapter(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate (@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initData();
    }

    private void initData ()
    {
        m_groupViewModel = viewModelProviders.of(this).get(GroupListViewModel.class);
        m_groupViewModel.getAllGroups().observe(this, new Observer<List<GroupEntity>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged (@Nullable final List<GroupEntity> groups)
            {
                // Update the cached copy of groups
                adapter.setGroups(groups);
                doListView();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView (@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                          Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.fragment_groups, container, false);

        //initialize widgets
        rv_groups = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_groups);
        tv_noGroups = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_noGroups);

        FloatingActionButton fab_add;
        fab_add = view.findViewById(R.id.fab_add);

        fab_add.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().startActivityForResult(new Intent(getContext(), CreateGroupActivity.class), Activities.CREATE_GROUP);
            }
        });

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(m_context);
        rv_groups.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        rv_groups.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        rv_groups.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(m_context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

        doListView();
        setHasOptionsMenu (true);

        return view;
    }

    /** Indicate on the UI that there are no groups to display. */
    private void showNoGroups ()
    {
        rv_groups.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tv_noGroups.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tv_noGroups.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.string_noGroups));
    }

    /**
     * Set the group list view content.
     */
    private void doListView ()
    {
        if (m_groupViewModel == null || m_groupViewModel.countGroups() == 0)
        {
            showNoGroups();
        }
        else
        {
            rv_groups.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv_noGroups.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume ()
    {
        super.onResume();
        doListView();
    }
}
```

Comment: hello delete "<LinearLayout>" uses  <LinearLayout

Comment: check ur xml code u write wrong "<LinearLayout>"

Comment: give height ***wrap_content*** to your TextView.

Comment: @sureshmadaparthi Sorry about the LinearLayout line. I've edited to show my original line. Something must have happened after copy and paste when I was writing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is due to your TextView having a height of `MATCH_PARENT`.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_noGroups"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

In this code, you're telling the `TextView` to stretch from the top of the `LinearLayout` to the bottom of the `LinearLayout`.

`LinearLayout` is a layout that adds views one by one if there is enough space. But if you tell a View to stretch all the way, then there's no more room to show the other views.

So for your `FloatingActionButton`, it's simply pushed off the screen.

It shows itself when the list is displayed, because in your Java code, you made the fully stretched **tv_noGroups** TextView `GONE`. This GONE hides the TextView and allows the `FloatingActionButton` to come back out.

If you want to fix this with your current xml file, there's two solutions.

1. Add weight to the **tv_noGroups** TextView. `android:layout_weight="1"`. You did the same for the RecyclerView which is why it could allow the FloatingActionButton to come out even when the RecyclerView stretches the whole screen.
2. Change height to "wrap_content" in the **tv_noGroups** TextView. Then replace `android:gravity="center"` with `android:layout_gravity="center"`.

However, this is just the explanation to fix the problem you're having with your layout.

I want to add some more words in saying that there's more Layouts to choose from and `LinearLayout` isn't a layout that's good for what you want to do.

Typically, if you want to use a `FloatingActionButton`, it's better to use a `ConstraintLayout` or `RelativeLayout` due to two reasons:

1. More freedom on where you place your Views
2. Views can overlap on top of each other, so your `FloatingActionButton` can hover over other components like your `RecyclerView`.

`LinearLayout` is really too restrictive in it's use, which caused you use Layouts inside of Layouts, which is actually a bad thing.

Here's a documentation published by Google about why you should avoid using nested layouts and how nesting layouts can decrease your app's performance: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout

Comment: Thanks for the 2 easy fixes, and explanation. I hate doing GUI's. Most of my career has been embedded systems without any GUI. I will try other layout types later.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ConstraintLayout, it's easier and cleaner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_groups"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_noGroups"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```